# Pyspark: Creating multiple descriptive columns based on groups

Tags: pyspark, databricks, feature-extraction

I'm trying to dabble in Pyspark and encountering some issues when i'm trying to create multiple descriptive columns. This is the dataset I have:

```
columns = ["Name", "Type","Amount", "Year"]
data = [("Bob", "Income", 150, 2022), ("Bob","Income", 100, 2021), ("Karen", "Income", 100, 2021), ("Bob", "Expense", 50, 2022), ("Bob", "Expense", 100, 2022), ("Bob", "Expense", 100, 2021)]
data = spark.createDataFrame(data).toDF(*columns)
```

I want to add numerous columns, with groupBy("Name"), such as:

- avg_income
- avg_income_2022
- avg_income_2021
- avg_expense
- avg_expense_2022
- avg_expense_2021

eventually I want my dataframe to look somethingalong the lines of this:

| Name | Type | Amount | Year | Avg_Income | Avg_income_2022 | Avg_income_2021 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | Income | 150 | 2022 | 100 | 125 | 50 |
| Bob | Income | 100 | 2022 | 100 | 125 | 50 |
| Bob | Income | 50 | 2021 | 100 | 125 | 50 |

Can anyone show me an example of how this would look like for one or two of the columns?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout the [groupBy](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.groupBy.html) and [agg](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.agg.html) functions

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import avg, col

avg_income = data.where(col('year') == '2022').groupBy('Name').agg(avg("Amount").alias("Avg_income_2022"))
data = data.join(avg_income, ['Name'])
```

Comment: This just create a seperate dataframe instead of it adding to my existing dataframe. Maybe imy explanation was insufficient but i want to add to my existing dataframe by filtering on expenses/Income and groupby name. And then i want to add the values to the dataframe I have

Comment: This does not make much sense, since one DataFrame is grouped and the other one is not. It would help if you could provide an example dataset that you want to have as an outcome

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I've updated the story. Hopefully this makes more sense now

Comment: Updated my answer. From there on you should be able to deduce more columns yourself.